# Getting Permission denied (publickey). error while setting hadoop cluster in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2

Hi I am trying to setup Hadoop cluster in AWS EC2 instance.

I did copy `sshkey_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys` file for all `namenode` and `datanode` clusters to interact each other. Still I am getting

> Permission denied (publickey)

while starting Hadoop namenode.

[image: Image with error]

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB8x7.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG8uk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are the permissions on the key correct? You want `-r--------`